# ExpressJS Public Files Not Being Served Once Deployed (NodeJS/Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static-files

Project directory structure is as follows:

```
my_project
server.js
app.js
|
| - public
|           ----------| images | javascripts | stylesheets
|           -------------- imgs ---scripts.js ---styles.css 
|
| - routes
|
| - views
|           ----------| partials
|           -------------- header.ejs, searchbar.ejs, footer.ejs
| (rendered views.ejs)
|
| 
| misc. files
```

Within my **header.ejs** file, this is the path to my .css file located in **public/stylesheets/style.css**: `href='/stylesheets/style.css'`

Within my **app.js** file, here is my code telling express to serve the public directory: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`. Additionally, I have also tried: `app.use(express.static('/public'));` but have not had any luck.

Currently both JS and CSS files are being served locally just fine, but when I deploy this application (and I have no control over the root directory or structure), it is not serving the files.

This is what I'm not sure how to handle -- locally, having the `'/'` in front of `href='/stylesheets/style.css'` works perfectly, but I know once deployed this is going to search the route of the domain and of course it's not going to be there.  But, if I remove the `'/'`, it stops working locally but may serve the file correctly once deployed.

How do I fix this issue? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest you `console.log(__dirname)` and `console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))` to see if both are exactly what you expect.  If `__dirname` is what you expect it to be and the files are where you say they are and you are using urls like `href='/stylesheets/style.css'`, it should work (like it does locally) so one of those things must not be as you expect.  You might also check file permissions to make sure your server can read those files.

Comment: FYI, `href='/stylesheets/style.css'` does not "search the root of your domain".  It only searches routes that you define and `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` tells it to search the `public` sub-directory for that path by searching `public/stylesheets/style.css` which is what you want.  You want the leading `/` on your URL.  The only problem to solve here is to make sure your server is looking for the files in the right place and has the right permissions to read them.

Comment: @jfriend00 I just tested `href='./stylesheets/style.css'` and my index.ejs (at root`'/'`) file was rendered perfectly with css styles in tact on the deployment server.  However, no other views were rendered with css styling even though they are within the same directory as the index.ejs file..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue.  For future searcher's who are experiencing the same issue, try setting up a dynamic path variable that you render via each route.  For example:

My **header.ejs** file contains the following link to the .css file: `<link rel='stylesheet' href='<%= path %>stylesheets/style.css'>`.

You can then pass a specific *path* into your desired *view.ejs* via its corresponding router.  For example, my **index.js** route contains something like this:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {  path: '' });
});
```

Since directory structure may vary from a local development environment to an actual production/testing server, doing this (if using a concept like a header partial) will allow you to dynamically serve your public assets.  For example, the rendered path to another view via its corresponding route may look like this:

```
router.get('/newdirectory', function(req, res) {
  res.render("new-view", { path: '../' });        
});
```

This will allow you to modify your public assets (scripts, images, stylesheets), etc. depending on its location relative to the file being requested.  Good luck!