# ExpressJS using EJS fail to load static assets when deployed on AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-amplify

I am developing a web app using Express JS and EJS view engine and it will be deployed on AWS Amplify. Everything works fine in localhost, but has an issue with loading static files (css, js) when I deploy it on Amplify. The detail of this issue is described as following:

**1. Issue description:**

- On Amplify, the root path of the website (*/index*) works fine, and the static files are loaded
  [___.amplifyapp.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnlZB.png)
- But when I go to the other path (*/register* for example), it cannot load the static files [___.amplifyapp.com/register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH7Rt.png)
- I notice that when loading static files, the ***pathname*** was automatically added to all the paths to the static files (in this case *`/register`* was added: the true path would be `https://myuser.amplifyapp.com/global/js/Base.js/` instead of `https://myuser.amplifyapp.com/register/global/js/Base.js/`)

**2. My source code structure like this:**

```
|   app.js
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
+---bin
+---dist
|   |   app.js
|   |   error.ejs
|   |   index.html
|   |   package.json
|   |   register.ejs
|   |   verify.ejs
|   +---assets
|   +---global
|   +---javascripts
+---node_modules
+---public
|   +---assets
|   +---global
|   +---javascripts
|   index.html
+---routes
\---views
```

- In app.js I already set the static folder for `'public'`:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

- In register.ejs I currently set the link to the static files like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="global/vendor/animsition/animsition.css">
<script src="global/vendor/animsition/animsition.js"></script>
```

- The build command I set in *package.json* (it copies all the necessary files and folders for deployment):

```yaml
"build": "del-cli dist && mkdir dist && ncp public dist && ncp views dist && copyfiles app.js dist && copyfiles package.json dist"
```

- I use Github to store my source code and deploy my app using AWS Amplify Console, by creating an application and connecting it to Github repository. This method allows my app is always re-deployed whenever I make change and push to Github. The config in `amplify.yaml` is:

```yaml
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

**3. What I have tried:** I have read a lot of issues in stackorverflow and followed their suggestions, but nothing works.

- I already tried to add `'/'` or `'../'` to the link to the static files:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/global/vendor/animsition/animsition.css">
<script src="/global/vendor/animsition/animsition.js"></script>
```

- I tried to pass the specific *path* as mentioned by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549618/expressjs-public-files-not-being-served-once-deployed-nodejs-express)
- I also tried to set static for the folders in *public* such as *assets, global* but nothing better
- I also moved all the views from *views* folder to *public* folder and change the views setting in source code, but the result was still the same: **Everything works fine in localhost but failed when deployed to AWS Amplify.**

How do I fix this issue? I would appreciate any advice from you. Thanks so much!

Comment: What is your really automatically added pathname? Does automatically added pathname match your project folder name or your domain or something? What is your `app.set('views', '???')`

Comment: @JackYu hi, the `pathname` added matches with the view name that I route to, e.g. `/register` or `/login`. `views` is set as `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` but event I change to `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'dist'));` it still does not work :)

Answer (score 2):

AWS Amplify is static web hosting service (only frontend), it’s not for nodejs + ejs.
it means you couldn’t create a server with specific port number in amplify with express, but amplify allow you use express to build REST api but not to render page.
I think you should put your website into EC2, instead of amplify.
You could take a look  [Amplify faqs](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/faqs)

Comment: thanks for your solution. I already tried this solution but when I create the folder structure in `dist` like you said, Amplify will return the error *502 ERROR The request could not be satisfied.* and as I checked in the build log, the reason of this error is `index.html` not in the `dist` folder, I think Amplify requires `index.html` in the `dist` folder, not in any sub-folder of `dist`. If I move `index.html` to the root folder like `app.js`, it's fail to load the home page even in localhost.

Comment: AWS Ampify is static web hosting service (only frontend), it’s not for nodejs + ejs. I think you should put your website into EC2, instead of ampify. You could take a look https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/faqs/

Comment: probably, but I don't understand why it works when I use all the views in form of `.html` and place them in the `public` folder, and still use Express router. I will find the other way or will use `.html` with Express since I have to deploy my web app on serverless environment. Thank you so much @Jack Yu

Comment: Because you use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` in express, express will public the resource in public folder which you assigned. You could access /abc.html after you put abc.html into public folder.